# SQL Server : distributed transaction conflict

Tags: sql-server, distributed-transactions

Given a SQL script:

1. Start a transaction. It is initiated from server X
2. Do a select into from a query involving table A into table B (= new table)
3. Select table A into table C (= new table)
4. Commit.

No errors happen. This is NOT a distributed transaction yet, since everything happens on 1 server.

Now let's say 3. becomes:

1. Select table A into table C, but table C is on a different server (I have to do this via `EXECUTE('SELECT * INTO ...') AT [remoteserver]` because 3 prefix syntax is allowed in the FROM clause but not in the INTO clause)

Now SQL Server tells me this statement (3) generates a conflict with another statement in the (now distributed) transaction.

To show you where the error is coming from and to prove that distributed transactions do actually work on my setup **I now comment out step 2)** !

Now the whole thing works. So step 2) makes the problem occur. But step 2) basically only does a joined select on table A and some other tables to generate table B and nothing else.

Why cannot step 3) execute without problems in that case (in the distributed transaction version), but the same non-distributed transaction version works flawlessly? And what conflict can there possibly be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys. Found out the problem, and it is interesting. It was something else. I did **not** mention that I also created table A, because I thought it had nothing to do with the problem, so:

Replace step 2) with

```
2) Create Table A **with** a primary key.
```

Now the non distributed version works, the distributed version does **not** (step 3 that is).

Replace step 2) with

```
2) Create Table A with **no** primary key
```

Now **both** versions work fine.

But I don't care really because the whole thing *also* works when I create the table **with** a primary key somewhere **before** the transaction. It is just that creating the primary key with the create table statement **in** the transaction causes 3) distributed version to not work.

If someone knows why please write it here :)

Comment: Until you commit, the table is only visible to its own connection.  The second connection is not allowed to operate on it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like query 2 and query 3 are not compatible.  To figure out why, investigate which locks each query causes.  One way to do that is:

1. Begin Transaction
2. Run query 2 (or 3)
3. Locks can be found in the view `sys.dm_tran_locks`.
4. Rollback or commit, doesn't matter

Perhaps you could append the resulting locks to your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I thought it had something to do with locks too, now not so sure. At least I have a remedy for the real problem now. See why in my own answer to my initial posting. If you have an answer to the real problem caused by the primary key please respond too to that, because it interests me. Thanks.